# Angularjs and custom directive including other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like create a custom directive that use the ui.bootstrap.tabs. For example my template will be

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="language in languages" active="$first">
    <tab-heading>
        <img ng-src="language.icon.thumbnail">
    </tab-heading>
    <input ui-if="!multiline" type="text" ng-model="model[language.id].value">
    <div ui-if="multiline">
        <textarea style="width:500px; height:300px;" type="text" 
                  ui-tinymce ng-model="model[language.id].value">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

And the directive is:

```
function() {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict : 'C',
            replace : true,
            scope : { label: '@', id: '@', multiline: '@', model: '=', languages: '=' },
            templateUrl: '/components/multilang-text/template.html'
        };
```

But it doesn't work! I have this [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/multidir?p0=multilangText&p1=tabset&p2=template&p3=%3Ctabset%20class=%22multilang-text%22%20id=%22%7B%7B%24index%7D%7D%22%20languages=%22languages%22%20model=%22property.value.translations%22%20label=%22%22%3E)

I think the problem is that each directive use a template...

Can you help me?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most probably with the replace; try setting it to `false`/leaving it out. Alternatively, wrap the template HTML in a container - e.g. a `<div>`. The reason is roughly that both your directive and `<tabset>` claim the element on which your directive is applied.

Also, there is no transclusion in your template; do you really need `transclude: true`?